Firewall rules are saying specific ports are opened. But actually closed
I have purchased an Ubuntu 22.04 vps. I tried to open port 2281, 2282 and 2283. Firewall rules saying ports are opened. But actually they are closed. I also tried using ufw. But nothing works.
Before Ubuntu 22, I purchased 24.04 and a simple ufw command opened those ports. And the application I am trying to use, was running there smoothly.
